# mitmproxy ignore-hosts cannot be accessed with firefox

Tags: mitmproxy

I tried to use `--ignore-hosts` to ignore some domains like

`mitmproxy --ignore-hosts .facebook.com`

I assume that "--ignore-hosts" means: ignored hosts will not be intercepted and would be just forwarded/passthru.

I can now proxy all sites with mitmproxy's CA and inspect the traffic.
However, I cannot browse `facebook.com` with Firefox at all and will get

```
    Secure Connection Failed

    An error occurred during a connection to www.facebook.com.

    The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
    Please contact the web site owners to inform them of this problem.
```

is it due to firefox? Or I understand it wrong and mitmproxy just refuse to process "ignored hosts"?!

Answer (score 1):

The `--ignore-hosts` option expects a regular expression. If you set it to `.facebook.com` it does not match `facebook.com` because the regular expression requires one additional character at the beginning.

If you want to ignore `facebook.com`, and all of it's subdomains you have to use the following regular expression:

```
mitmproxy --ignore-hosts '^(.+\.)?facebook\.com:443$'
```

See also https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/howto-ignoredomains/#tutorial

Comment: the regxp is not the issue. after I run `mitmproxy --ignore-hosts '^(.+\.)?facebook\.com:443$'`, I can access all webb sites (with mitmproxy CA) except facebook.com.  The ignored host is not accessible.

Comment: @Open developer options in your web browser and check what domains it tries to access. Facebook my use cdn sites that are not subdomains of facebok.com.

Comment: it is not about the domain matching. the question is why "ignored" domain is denied.

Comment: @rnd_nr_gen If you specify the ignore domain to be `.facebook.com` and the domain Firefox tries to connect to is `www.facebook.com` which isn't covered by the regex `.facebook.com` then the connection will not be ignored (thus intercepted) and not accepted by Firefox (unless you install the mitmproxy root cert in Firefox).

Comment: firefox has mitmproxy CA imported. Every page will be intercepted by mitmproxy with its own CA. Only facebook.com (in this example) page cannot be loaded in firefox at all.